# Geo Blocking Youtube Live stream Videos in specific regions through Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I'm working currently on a project with youtube live streaming. The problem is next:
 - from Youtube API playground it's easy to make an api call from Youtube Data Api with geo block in specified countries **contentDetails.regionRestriction**.  But it's simply doesn't change anything the video still has the same geo restrictions as it was before. Does anyone has any ideas why this endpoint doesn't works?